# Extract data based on a list of time points from different individuals

Tags: r, indexing, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am trying to extract rows of a dataset based on a list of time points needed for different individuals. What is the way to do it in base R?

Here is the original dataset:

```
data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=3), time=1:3, y=c(1:9))
```

Here is the list of time points for each id which I want to use to extract the data:

```
$`1` #this is id 1
 [1] 1 2 #these are the time points I need for id 1

$`2`
 [1] 1 3

$`3`
 [1] 2 3
```

So the final data looks like this:

```
  id time y
   1    1 1
   1    2 2
   2    1 4
   2    3 6
   3    2 8
   3    3 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways following the same logic.

In base R -

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(p, q) subset(data, id == q & time %in% p), 
        lst, names(lst)))
```

Or using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

purrr::imap_dfr(lst, ~data %>% filter(id == .y, time %in% .x))

#  id time y
#1  1    1 1
#2  1    2 2
#3  2    1 4
#4  2    3 6
#5  3    2 8
#6  3    3 9
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=3), time=1:3, y= 1:9)
lst <- list(`1` = c(1, 2), `2` = c(1, 3), `3` = c(2, 3))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you@Ronak Shah!

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah. Sorry another followup question: what if I have repeated time points in the `lst`? For example, `lst <- list(`1` = c(1, 1, 2), `2` = c(1, 3, 3), `3` = c(2, 2, 3))`. It seems that the rows with repeated time points under the same id are removed by your code (is that the problem caused by `%in%`?). How do I still keep those duplicated rows?

Answer (score 1):

One approach using a left join:

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=3), time=1:3, y=c(1:9))
want <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, each = 2), 
                   time = c(1,2,1,3,2,3))

merge(want, df, all.x = TRUE)
```

Result

```
  id time y
1  1    1 1
2  1    2 2
3  2    1 4
4  2    3 6
5  3    2 8
6  3    3 9
```

Comment: (I'm less sure about the best way to convert your list to a data frame. May come back later to figure that out.)

Comment: Thank you@Jon Spring. Exactly, preferrably I want to bypass converting the list to a data frame because I need to replicate this process many times and supposedly data frames could slow things down. But anyway I upvoted your answer!